# Read from database, single rows (Joomla framework)

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I use this code to read from data base:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array('category_name', 'category_short_description'));
$query->from('#__redshop_category');
$query->where('category_id = 1');

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

How can i read once element, for example extra *category_name* and extra *category_short_description*

Here is also offical joomla wiki, but without single output: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Here what i have doing, but that's not work:
**echo $results;** ->output:ARRAY
**echo $results['category_name'];** -> without output, empty (In database rows are not empty)

How can i do this?

Comment: use the `print_r($results)` to check what you are getting in the variable `$results`.

Comment: I see now my output, and that is correct: ARRAY ([0] => STDCLASS OBJECT ( [CATEGORY_NAME] => For childrens [CATEGORY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION] =>TEST)) - it's possible to read once items?

Comment: Then use the `echo $results[0]->category_name;` this will give the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loadObject()` instead of `loadObjectList()` to retrieve just the first row:

```
$results = $db->loadObject();
echo $results->category_name;
```

If you want an associative array instead of an object, there is `loadAssoc()`:

```
$results = $db->loadAssoc();
echo $results['category_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch single row you can use

```
$result = $db->loadObject()
```

instead of

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList()
```

and then you can access data by

```
$result->category_name;
$result->category_short_description;
```